# Custom Spinner modify style of First element

Tags: android, user-interface, textview, spinner

We created the custom Spinner to modify the style of first element. All is ok, but we noticed that sometime no only first element style was changed... We try to investigate but didn't find any problem.

1. getDropDownView of custom spinner

   ```
   public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

   if (row instanceof TextView)
   {
       if (position == 0)
       {
               ((TextView) row).setTypeface(((TextView) row).getTypeface(), Typeface.ITALIC);
       }
   }

   return (row);
   ```

   }
2. Visual problem

[image]

Can you, please, understand WHY it is happened?

**UPDATE**
This idea didn't work:

```
    if (position == 0)
    {
        crossBorderPointName.setTypeface((TextView) row).setTypeface(((TextView) row).getTypeface(), Typeface.ITALIC);
    }
    else
    {
        crossBorderPointName.setTypeface((TextView) row).setTypeface(((TextView) row).getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL);
    }
```

Comment: yet another `if witout else` ... because of AbsListView reuse the views ... [yes, it applies to Spinner, too](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70)

Comment: sorry, can you, please, give a little bit more information? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried for position != 0 to set a NORMAL typeface?